# How to embed HTML iFrame into mkdocs/material?

Tags: mkdocs

I'd like to embed an HTML file into an MkDocs/Material page.

I'm trying something like what's below, but getting a 404 error.

Any idea of the right way to do this?

```
<div class="map">
  <iframe src="map.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

For what it's worth, a link like this **does** work, but I'd like the option to embed it in the current page.

```
[Show a map](map.html)
```

Comment: can you try absolute path like `mydomain.com/map.html` ?

Answer (score 1):

404 error seems that  map.html is located somewhere else, while `[show a map](map.html)` may generate correct link. `map.html` is relative to viewing page, so I recommend to:

- get absolute url of map.html file, e.g. When you click on Show a map what is absolute URL in browser location bar?
- put that absolute URL into iframe src="absolute url"
- you may make the absolute url relative - based on address current address in location bar

Answer (score 0):

Actually the index.md files behave differently. Relative paths work with them, but I also found a workaround for keeping it at relative paths: I went up one level to root then I used it as if it in the folder that gets generated in the `site` folder when you run `mkdocs build` See it in my sample docs here: https://agu3rra.github.io/volpy/ Link to the repo is on the top right corner.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice I like to use the following structure:

```
-- docs:

  -- assets:

     -- map.html

  -- index.md

  -- PAGE_WITH_MAP.md
```

Now within your PAGE_WITH_MAP you should be able to find the the image with:

```
<div class="map">
  <iframe src="../assets/map.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Note: for the index.md you can just use assets/map.html.